# should Bloc pattern be used for flutter textfield and if yes how?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

So I'm new to Bloc but I understand how it works from previously working on native android development, but what I'm trying to understand is should it be implemented to create something like a TextField. Now, keep in mind that I am trying to reuse this TextField multiple times and I want the bloc pattern to dynamically validate the input but should I implement it completely **like handle the text inputted by the user?**

**what I've done is I've created a simple bloc pattern for the text field to handle the user input but it does not save the values from time to time it overwrites the previous value and the cursor keeps moving to the beginning of the text**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:competitionapp/data_model/events/formTextFieldEvent.dart';
import 'package:competitionapp/data_model/states/formTextFieldState.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

FormTextFieldBloc bloc = FormTextFieldBloc();

class FormTextFieldBloc extends Bloc<FormTextFieldEvent, FormTextFieldState> {
  void onChanged(String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty)
//      todo change to handle errors
      this.add(TextChangedEvent("error"));
    else
      this.add(TextChangedEvent(value));
  }

  @override
  FormTextFieldState get initialState => FormTextFieldState.initState();

  @override
  Stream<FormTextFieldState> mapEventToState(FormTextFieldEvent event) async* {
    if (event is TextChangedEvent) {
      print("value received: ${event.eventText}");
      yield FormTextFieldState(event.eventText);
    }
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:competitionapp/data_model/blocModels/formTextFieldBloc.dart';
import 'package:competitionapp/data_model/states/formTextFieldState.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class FormTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _controller;
  final String hint;
  final IconData iconData;
  final TextInputType inputType;

  final int maxLines;
  final int maxLength;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final FormTextFieldBloc formTextFieldBloc;

  FormTextField(this._controller, this.formTextFieldBloc,
      {this.hint,
      this.iconData,
      this.inputType: TextInputType.text,
      this.maxLines: 1,
      this.maxLength,
      this.padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 5)});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: padding,
      child: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: formTextFieldBloc,
        builder: (context, FormTextFieldState state) {
          if (state.text.isNotEmpty && state.text != null) {
            _controller.text = state.text;
            print("state text: ${state.text}");
          }
          return TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              print(value);
              formTextFieldBloc.onChanged(_controller.text);
            },
            onEditingComplete: (){
              print(_controller.text);
            },
            maxLength: maxLength ?? maxLength,
            maxLines: maxLines,
            keyboardType: inputType,
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0)),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0)),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0)),
              hintText: hint,
              hintStyle:
                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                iconData,
                size: 16,
                color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using provider? Its simpler than bloc and works fine, although, it's all up to your choice.

Comment: do you mean bloc provider? or provider as in the state management

Comment: The state management one

Comment: [here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_form_validation) is an example.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here happens because the value on TextField is always overridden on `_controller.text = state.text;` and continuously updated on `onChanged()`. One way to approach this is to only update the TextField values when the entry is submitted i.e. on `onFieldSubmitted()`

You can check for a similar approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68740918/2497859). While it doesn't use a Stream to listen for changes, the TextField value needs to be updated with a desired format.