# Flutter TextFormField display value with NumberFormat

Tags: flutter

I'd like to be able to display the value entered in TextFormField with `NumberFormat('###,##0.00', 'en_US')`.

There are no issues in the conversion, but I'm having issues displaying the value of `formattedPrice` in the TextFormField. I'd also like to set the default value of TextFormField as `'0.00'`. In my sample code below, the TextFormField restricts input to only have a single decimal symbol/separator and two decimal values.

I'm fine with `.00` decimals not displayed when there are no decimals present in the TextFormField value during input, but I'd like the two decimal places format be placed when the value is entered.

| TextFormField value displayed when typing | TextFormField value displayed when entered |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 123.00 |
| 123.5 | 123.50 |
| 123.54 | 123.54 |
| 12,345 | 12,345.00 |
| 12,345.6 | 12,345.60 |

#### Minimal Repro

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _subscriptionFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _subscriptionPriceController = TextEditingController();
  NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat('###,###.00', 'en_US');
  NumberFormat numSanitizedFormat = NumberFormat('en_US');
  var currency = 'USD';

  void _validate() {
    if (_subscriptionFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _subscriptionFormKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,2}')),
            ],
            keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            validator: (cost) {
              if (cost == null || cost.isEmpty) {
                return 'Empty';
              }
              return null;
            },
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,

            /// TODO TextFormField default value
            /// I'd like to be to set '0.00' value by default
            controller: _subscriptionPriceController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Price',
              prefixText:
                  NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: currency).currencySymbol,
            ),
            onChanged: (price) {
              /// TODO Display [formattedPrice] in TextFormField
              var formattedPrice = numFormat.format(double.parse(price));
              debugPrint('Formatted $formattedPrice');
              var numSanitized = numSanitizedFormat.parse(price);
              debugPrint('Sanitized: $numSanitized');
              _subscriptionPriceController.value = TextEditingValue(
                text: price,
                selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: price.length),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _validate,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Update:

Thanks to @Andrej for suggesting to use `onFieldSubmitted()` instead of `onChange()`. I've updated my code with the fix included. I hope this will help other developers blocked with similar issue.

#### Code with the fix:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _subscriptionFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _subscriptionPriceController = TextEditingController();
  final NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat('###,##0.00', 'en_US');
  final NumberFormat numSanitizedFormat = NumberFormat('en_US');
  var currency = 'USD';
  var defaultPrice = '0.00';

  void _validate() {
    if (_subscriptionFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _subscriptionFormKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,2}')),
            ],
            keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            validator: (cost) {
              if (cost == null || cost.isEmpty) {
                return 'Empty';
              }
              return null;
            },
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,

            /// Set TextFormField default value
            controller: _subscriptionPriceController..text = defaultPrice,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Price',
              prefixText:
                  NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: currency).currencySymbol,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              var textFieldNum = _subscriptionPriceController.value.text;
              var numSanitized = numSanitizedFormat.parse(textFieldNum);
              _subscriptionPriceController.value = TextEditingValue(
                /// Clear if TextFormField value is 0
                text: numSanitized == 0 ? '' : '$numSanitized',
                selection:
                    TextSelection.collapsed(offset: '$numSanitized'.length),
              );
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (price) {
              /// Set value to 0 if TextFormField value is empty
              if (price == '') price = '0';
              final formattedPrice = numFormat.format(double.parse(price));
              debugPrint('Formatted $formattedPrice');
              _subscriptionPriceController.value = TextEditingValue(
                text: formattedPrice,
                selection:
                    TextSelection.collapsed(offset: formattedPrice.length),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _validate,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the price to be formatted when the text field is entered.

If yes, just add this code to your `TextFormField`:

```dart
            onFieldSubmitted: (price) {
              final formattedPrice = numFormat.format(double.parse(price));
              debugPrint('Formatted $formattedPrice');
              _subscriptionPriceController.value = TextEditingValue(
                text: formattedPrice,
                selection:
                    TextSelection.collapsed(offset: formattedPrice.length),
              );
            },
```

To add the initial value to the text field:

```dart
final _subscriptionPriceController = TextEditingController(text: '0.00');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me a lot of time. Using `onFieldSubmitted` works best instead of `onChanged((String value) { })`.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you. Have a nice day :)